# SQL Server clone stored procedure including grants

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, clone

Can I clone a stored procedure including grants to a new name?

```
create procedure y as clone x
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product but I am not aware of any DBMS product that would support that. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: MS SQL Server. 
I would prefer a generell solution in SQL, but as you say there is none at all.
Being able to copy any database object including grant/rights to a new name would also be logical to me.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I can't understand how to consider my question unclear or useless.

Comment: There is no generic magic that will do whatever it is you intend. And it is your intention that is very unclear. Generally speaking, duplication of anything (data, code, etc) is something you should strive to avoid. Here it seems that is your intention. So ... is it? Why would you as a developer want to create more code that does the exact same thing? Seems this is more likely a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Perhaps a synonym will be useful?

Comment: I would just use the SSMS > Generate Scripts tool, and simply change the name of in the resulting script.

Comment: Cloning a thing to a second with other name is a very clear intention. If I can create some alias, that will be fine too, how can that be done? And may be also one creating a new object when I change the object on one name only, but don't need that for current problem, just for interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this SQL Server script:

```
Declare @sql_create NVarchar(MAX)
Declare @sql_grants NVarchar(MAX)
Declare @sp_name Varchar(MAX)
Declare @sp_new_name Varchar(MAX)
declare @object_id int


set @sp_name = '<YourSPName>'
set @sp_new_name = '<YourSPNewName>'

-- Get SP...
Select      @object_id = o.object_id, 
            @sql_create = Replace(definition, @sp_name, @sp_new_name)
From        sys.sql_modules m
inner join  sys.objects o on m.object_id = o.object_id
where       m.definition like '%' + @sp_name +'%'
and         o.type = 'P'


-- Get all permissions

SELECT  @sql_grants = COALESCE(@sql_grants + '; ', '') +
  (
    dp.state_desc + ' ' +
    dp.permission_name collate latin1_general_cs_as + 
    ' ON ' + '[' + s.name + ']' + '.' + '[' + Replace(o.name , @sp_name, @sp_new_name) + ']' +
    ' TO ' + '[' + dpr.name + ']'
  ) 
FROM sys.database_permissions AS dp
  INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON dp.major_id=o.object_id
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
  INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS dpr ON dp.grantee_principal_id=dpr.principal_id
WHERE dpr.name NOT IN ('public','guest')
and o.object_id = @object_id

-- Optional    
Print (@sql_create)  --Note: will cut off at TextWidth!
Print (@sql_grants)  

-- Execute queries...
EXEC (@sql_create)
EXEC (@sql_grants)
```

I hope that helps you!

Comment: That's to complicated. It's easier to create the second procedure new and set the same grants then.

Comment: I understood that you need to do it programmatically ... You could create an SP and pass it as parameters the name of the SP to be cloned and the name of the new SP, that way you could execute it only with 'CloneSP <name_orig> <new_name>' .